# how to put the CSS class name inside the MUI createTheme palette color name instead of the hardcode name

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

## how to put the CSS class name inside the Material-UI(MUI) createTheme palette color name instead of the hardcode name.

```js
 const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        light: "#66b53f",
        main: **"I want to put css class name here"**,
        dark: "#66b53f",
        contrastText: "#fff",
      },
      secondary: {
        light: "#ff7961",
        main: "#f44336",
        dark: "#ba000d",
        contrastText: "#000",
      },
    },
  });
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that, [MUI palette](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#customization) is for colors.

Comment: Because I'm going to create some customize css classes where changing one css color will change the color of the whole project so I want to put css classes here.

Comment: Doing such will mess up your theming while using ThemeProvider hook! Why don't you define your custom classes through MuiCssBaseLine ?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, A better place to define your custom classes inside your Theme is to define them within components/MuiCssBaseLine :

```
 const theme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      primary: {
        main: "#66b53f",
        dark: "#66b53f",
      },
      secondary: {
        main: "#f44336",
        dark: "#ba000d",
      },
    },
    components : {
       MuiCssBaseLine : {
         styleOverrides : {
           body : {
             "& .custom-css-class" : {
                  color : "white",
                  bgcolor : "grey",
                  ... /* More stuffs */
            }
           }
         }
       }
    }
  });
```

then using *className="custom-css-class"* would be globally available to every child component wrapped within your ThemeProvider. You also need  ,imported at top of your app right after Theme context.

```
import { CssBaseLine , ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material"

export default function App() {
/* Rest of your code */
return (
     <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseLine />
      <YourApp />
      <div className="custom-css-class">custom-styled-stuff</div>
     </ThemeProvider>
      );
```

}